# Autostart of GTK application failing

Tags: linux, gtk, debian, beagleboneblack

I have a GTK application that runs perfectly when run from the desktop or a terminal window.

I created a myprog.desktop file in ~/.config/autostart:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyName
Path=~/...blah../MyApp
Exec=./myapp
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

This creates an icon which I can double-click, and the code runs. However it does not run when the window manager starts, as intended. I get the error

```
XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
```

in `~/.xsession-errors.old`

Any ideas what is happening here? Platform is Beaglebone Black, revision C (Debian).

Comment: have you considered using your https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc?

Comment: Tried that: same error occurs, application does not run.

Comment: how about a `sleep 5; start application`? (in .xinitrc)

Comment: Yes, tried sleeping. It causes the entire device to freeze when the application runs. Hard to understand why, nothing in the log, and because it's in a startup file is awkward to fix!

Comment: I am having better luck running the code from .xsessionrc !

Comment: It freezes because it blocks the startup procedure. You would need to add `(sleep 5; ./myapp) &`, that is, background it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code from `.xsessionrc` would appear to work nicely. I run it as
`/usr/bin/sudo ./myapp` - just to be sure!

Comment: don't use `sudo` *just to be sure*. use it only if you need super-user priviliges; if you don't know, don't use it.